If you are pedaling heel down does it indicate the saddle is too low?
And vice versa; if you are pedaling toe down, does it always indicate the saddle height is too high?

No, not necessarily, some people pedal slightly heel down, other people slightly heel up. Especially if the angle is consistent throughout the whole circle, I would not make any conclusions from just that.
